Who is the black-haired character with a white and black / dark blue costume appearing in the parody of "A Different World"?
In X-Men '97 (Season 1, Episode 4: "Motendo / Lifedeath - Part 1"), there's a scene where Mojo presents potential X-Men-themed TV shows, including a parody of A Different World. It features several X-Men characters, but one in particular has me stumped.
This character has black hair and wears a costume that's white upper part (neck/chest) and a black (or dark blue) lower part. 
I've included a screenshot (character circled in red) for reference.

Can anyone identify this character?

That's Northstar (Jean-Paul Beaubier), a member of the Canadian superhero team, Alpha Flight.
He was created by Chris Claremont and John Byrne, and first appeared in Uncanny X-Men Vol. 1 #120 (April, 1979).


Alpha Flight Vol. 1 #25 (August, 1985)

